# switching pages in ViewPager is not smooth

Tags: android

I am using Viewpager to switch between pages. I have five pages in ViewPager which are getting data from my custom cursor adapter. The problem is switching pages is not smooth, it's choppy. What am i doing wrong ? Any help is really appreciated .

//MYPAGER

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    public int getCount() 
    {
        return 5;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) 
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view;

        SharedPreferences myoptions = getSharedPreferences("options", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = myoptions.edit();    

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_tasks, null);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

           //getting list view
           lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        MyAdapter adapter1;

        switch (position) {
        case 0:

            prefEditor.putInt("filter", 5);
            prefEditor.commit();

            if(selectedList!=null)
            {
                cursor1= managedQuery(uri, PROJECTION, where +" AND "+ taskColumns.LIST+ "= ?"
                    +" AND "+ taskColumns.DONE+ "= ?"
                        ,new String[] {selectedList,"0"}, sortingOrder);
            }
             else
                cursor1= managedQuery(uri, PROJECTION, where+" AND "+ taskColumns.DONE+ "= ?",new String[] {"0"}, sortingOrder);


           if (cursor1 != null)
           {
              cursor1.moveToFirst();

           }

           adapter1 = new MyAdapter(tasks.this,cursor1);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter1);

            break;
        case 1:

            prefEditor.putInt("filter", 4);
            prefEditor.commit();


            if(selectedList!=null)
            {
                cursor1= managedQuery(uri, PROJECTION, taskColumns.LIST+ "= ?"
                        ,new String[] {selectedList}, sortingOrder);
            }
             else
                 cursor1= managedQuery(uri, PROJECTION, where,null, sortingOrder); 

               if (cursor1 != null)
               {
                   cursor1.moveToFirst();
               }

               adapter1 = new MyAdapter(tasks.this,cursor1);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter1);

            break;
        case 2:

            prefEditor.putInt("filter", 1);
            prefEditor.commit();

            if(selectedList!=null)
            {
                cursor1= managedQuery(uri, PROJECTION, where +" AND "+ taskColumns.LIST+ "= ?"
                        ,new String[] {selectedList}, sortingOrder);
            }
             else
                 cursor1= managedQuery(uri, PROJECTION, where,null, sortingOrder);

               if (cursor1 != null)
               {
                   cursor1.moveToFirst();
               }

               adapter1 = new MyAdapter(tasks.this,cursor1);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter1);

            break;
        case 3:

            prefEditor.putInt("filter", 2);
            prefEditor.commit();

            if(selectedList!=null)
            {
                cursor1= managedQuery(uri, PROJECTION, where +" AND "+ taskColumns.LIST+ "= ?"
                        ,new String[] {selectedList}, sortingOrder);
            }
             else
                 cursor1= managedQuery(uri, PROJECTION, where,null, sortingOrder);

               if (cursor1 != null)
               {
                   cursor1.moveToFirst();
               }

               adapter1 = new MyAdapter(tasks.this,cursor1);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter1);
            break;
        case 4:

            prefEditor.putInt("filter", 3);
            prefEditor.commit();

            if(selectedList!=null)
            {
                cursor1= managedQuery(uri, PROJECTION, where +" AND "+ taskColumns.LIST+ "= ?"
                        ,new String[] {selectedList}, sortingOrder);
            }
             else
                 cursor1= managedQuery(uri, PROJECTION, where,null, sortingOrder);   

            if (cursor1 != null)
               {
                cursor1.moveToFirst();
               }

            adapter1 = new MyAdapter(tasks.this,cursor1);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter1);
            break;
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() 
    {
        return null;
    }
```

}

//custom adapter

```
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView task;
    public TextView note;
    public ImageView note_img;
    public TextView priority;
    public CheckBox done;
    public TextView showingByList;
    public TextView space;
    public LinearLayout b;
}

public class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private final int taskIndex;
    private final LayoutInflater Inflater;
    private final int doneIndex;
    private final int priorIndex;
    private final int rowIndex;
    private final int taskListIndex;
    private final int NoteIndex;
    boolean innewView;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) 
    {
        super(context, c);

        this.taskIndex = c.getColumnIndex(taskColumns.TASK);
        this.priorIndex = c.getColumnIndex(taskColumns.PRIORITY);
        this.doneIndex = c.getColumnIndex(taskColumns.DONE);
        this.rowIndex = c.getColumnIndex(taskColumns._ID);
        this.taskListIndex = c.getColumnIndex(taskColumns.LIST);
        this.NoteIndex = c.getColumnIndex(taskColumns.NOTE);

        this.Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

     @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
     {

            View v = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_row, parent, false);              
            innewView=true;

            return v;

     }

     @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

         final ViewHolder viewHolder;

         if(innewView)
         {

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.task = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.task);
                 viewHolder.note = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note);
                 viewHolder.note_img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.note_img);
                 viewHolder.priority = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.priority);
                 viewHolder.done = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
                 viewHolder.b=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.task_layout);
                 viewHolder.showingByList = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tasklist);

                 view.setTag(viewHolder);        
         }
         else    
             viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

         innewView=false;

         final String task = cursor.getString(taskIndex);
         String TaskNote = cursor.getString(NoteIndex);
         int prior= cursor.getInt(priorIndex);
         int taskDone= cursor.getInt(doneIndex);
         final long id=cursor.getLong(rowIndex);


         int uniqueyindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(taskColumns.UNIQUEY);

         if(TaskNote==null)
         {
         viewHolder.note.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         viewHolder.note_img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
         else
         {
             if(TaskNote.length()<1)
             {
                 viewHolder.note.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 viewHolder.note_img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }
             else{
         viewHolder.note.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.note_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
         } 

         if(showbyList){


             String taskList = cursor.getString(taskListIndex);
             if(taskList==null)
             {

                 ContentValues valuey=new ContentValues(); 
                 valuey.put(taskColumns.LIST_ID, "0");
                    valuey.put(taskColumns.LIST, "personal");
                    Uri mUry = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri,id);
                    getContentResolver().update(mUry, valuey,null,null);
                    taskList="personal";
             }      

               // viewHolder.showingByList.setTypeface(tf);

             viewHolder.b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             viewHolder.space=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.space);
             viewHolder.space.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             if(cursor.moveToPrevious()){


             int comparedResult= taskList.compareTo(cursor.getString(taskListIndex));

             if(comparedResult==0)
             {

                 viewHolder.showingByList.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
             }

             else{

                 viewHolder.showingByList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 viewHolder.showingByList.setText(taskList.toUpperCase());

             }



             }
             else{

                 viewHolder.showingByList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 viewHolder.showingByList.setText(taskList.toUpperCase());

             }

             cursor.moveToNext();

             viewHolder.showingByList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
             {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                }

             });
         }


         viewHolder.b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_drawable1);

         if(toModify.contains((int)id))
             viewHolder.b.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_blue);

         viewHolder.task.setText(task);

         if(TaskNote!=null)
         viewHolder.note.setText(TaskNote);

         if(taskDone==1){
         viewHolder.done.setChecked(true);
             viewHolder.task.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.smooth));
             viewHolder.note.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.smooth));
             viewHolder.note_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.note_done2);
         viewHolder.priority.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.priornone);
         }
         else{
             viewHolder.done.setChecked(false);
             viewHolder.task.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkthemed_text));
             viewHolder.note.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkthemed_note));
             viewHolder.note_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.note2);
             if(prior==1){
         viewHolder.priority.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.priornone);
                     }
             else{
             viewHolder.priority.setBackgroundResource(R.color.priority_2); 
            }
         }
         }


}
```

Comment: Stop doing disk I/O (`getSharedPreferences()`) on each `instantiateItem()`, and then use `StrictMode` and Traceview to examine where else you may be going wrong.

Comment: I followed **Commonsware** suggestion , found out that adapter is taking too much time inflating layouts during TraceView. I was using three linear layouts for listVIew rows, so i just changed the Parentlayout to relative layout & arranged childviews to get the desired output. That worked for me, now viewpager is smooth. Thanks Commonsware.

Answer (score 6):

In the future, try posting a little less code. As in, try to isolate the specific areas that you may think the problem is occurring in. I understand that you may not know, and in this case dumping both your `Adapters` is alright. Just know that it's slightly easier for anyone to help you when there's less code to read over.

As far as what you can do, you should try using `setOffScreenPageLimit` from `ViewPager`.

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

[Here are the docs for it.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)

**Example**

```
    YOURPAGER.setOffscreenPageLimit(LIMIT);
```

Comment: i have already used myPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4). But Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

you can set in you manifest "android:hardwareAccelerated="true"". It's very smooth with that